# Akka Http return 404 Not Found

Tags: scala, http, akka, http-status-code-404, akka-http

I'm trying to achieve very simple thing.

Say, I have a REST API. When I call

```
/api/recipe/1
```

I'd like to a resource as a json to be returned.

When I hit

```
/api/recipe/2
```

a 404 Not Found HTTP response should be returned. Simple as that.

Clearly I'm missing something about how routing directives work, as I'm not able to compose them to respect above-mentioned logic.

Unfortunately I was unable to find any concrete example and official documentation isn't particularly helpful.

I'm trying something like this but the code gives compilation error:

```
class RecipeResource(recipeService: RecipeService)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) extends DefaultJsonProtocol {

  implicit val recipeFormat = jsonFormat1(Recipe.apply)

  val routes = pathPrefix("recipe") {
    (get & path(LongNumber)) { id =>
      complete {
        recipeService.getRecipeById(id).map {
          case Some(recipe) => ToResponseMarshallable(recipe)
          // type mismatch here, akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable 
          // is required
          case None => HttpResponse(StatusCodes.NotFound)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Update

Here's the code of `recipeService` for greater clarity:

```
class RecipeService(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) {

  def getRecipeById(id: Long): Future[Option[Recipe]] = {
    id match {
      case 1 => Future.successful(Some(Recipe("Imperial IPA")))
      case _ => Future.successful(None)
    }
  }
}
```

The compilation error I get:

```
[error] /h......../....../...../RecipeResource.scala:22: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Object]
[error]  required: akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable
[error]         recipeService.getRecipeById(id).map {
[error]                                             ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

### Update 2

Based on *leachbj*'s answer I got rid of needless pattern matching in the route. Now the code compiles and looks like this:

```
class RecipeResource(recipeService: RecipeService)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) extends DefaultJsonProtocol {

  implicit val recipeFormat = jsonFormat1(Recipe.apply)

  val routes = pathPrefix("recipe") {
    (get & path(LongNumber)) { id =>
      complete(recipeService.getRecipeById(id))
    }
  }
}
```

When the recipe exists (e.g. `/api/recipe/1`) I get the JSON response and `200 OK`, which is expected.

Now, in case of the non-existent resource (e.g. `/api/recipe/2`) the response in empty, but `200 OK` status code is received.

My question is, how can I tweak akka-http to be able to `complete(Future[None[T]])` that would return `404 Not found`.

I'm looking for a generic approach that would work for any `Future[None]` return value.

Comment: What is the return type of `getRecipeById`?

Comment: ``Future[Option[Recipe]]``

Comment: So, what do you get when you run the query for that id? Do you get a None?

Comment: I've just a simple stub that returns ``Some`` in case of id is 1 and ``None`` otherwise. The code has been added to the post.

Comment: What's the compiler error? Can you post that?

Comment: Basically it expects ``akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable`` as return type of the closure. The compiler output has been added to the post.

Comment: You're returning two incompatible types. You should have an implicit marshaller in scope. Calling `ToResponseMarshallable` is the smell I'm smelling here.

EDIT: i just had a look at some of my Akka-Http code...I return a tuple of `StatusCode` -> `response` and don't futz  with ToResponseMarshallable at all.

Comment: Could you eventually post some routing code that conditionally returns: a) an object that is later marshaled into response, b) the empty  404 response? That would help a lot, cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you `complete(Future[Option[T]])` and there is a suitable Json Marshaller available the Akka will return the response as json if the value is `Some(v)` or an empty 200 response for `None`.  If you use spray-json create a `RootJsonFormat[T]` implicit and add `import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport._`. There are similar support implicits for other marshalling libraries.

To generate a 404 for `None` you need to wrap the `complete` with the [`rejectEmptyResponse`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.9/java/http/routing-dsl/directives/misc-directives/rejectEmptyResponse.html) directive.

Comment: Thanks, I did refactor the code as suggested. Now in case of ``Some`` I receive JSON and 200 OK, but in case of ``None``, I get obviously no response, but still 200 OK. Now I wonder if this is somehow default in akka-http or whether it can be adjusted.

Comment: Please see updated text, the rejectEmptyResponse directive is what you need.